# Using SPSiteDataQuery and only getting Items which are searchable

Tags: list, search, spsitedataquery

Is there a possibility to get only the items from documentlibrarys where the documentlibrary is searchable. I think the property on the splist is nocrawl.

I found a link where is written that there is an attribut "WithIndex" but it slows down the performance. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.lists.aspx

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Why aren't you using SharePoint search possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done it by creating Booleanfield in the content type and searching for that.